# Highstock, Dynamically add Points, a definied time span at the beginning

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following issue:

I want to dynamically update a hightstock Chart with Points from Ajax Calls. For Example i use setInterval(addPoints,3000); How can i develope the code, that the highstock Charts display an definied time, e.g. 1 Minute, and the Chart beginn to draw from the Left without this "time poping and squeezing? For a testrun i tried to you predifned null points, but the interval is not fix.

```
var value1="valueNo1";
var value2="valueNo2";


var color1="green";
var color2="red";


$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{
             chart: {
                 type: 'spline',
                 zoomtype: 'z'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            navigator: {
                top: 500
            },    
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },    
            rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 30,
                type: 'second',
                text: '30s'
            }, {
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {  
                count: 2,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '2M'
            }, {                    
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 1
        },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'

            }
});
});
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();


var ct = (new Date()).getTime();

// addAxis

chart.addAxis({ labels: { format: '{value}' , style: {color: color1 } }, title: { text: value1 , style: {color: color1} } ,   lineColor: color1, lineWidth: 0, opposite:true } );

chart.addAxis({ labels: {  format: '{value}', style: {color: color2 } }, title: { text: value2 , style: {color: color2} } ,   lineColor: color2, lineWidth: 0 } );

// addSeries

chart.addSeries({ "name": "value1","data": [], yAxis: 2, marker: {enabled:true, radius: 5 }});



// addPoint
var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();
chart.series[0].addPoint([current_time+64000, null], false);

addPoints = function(){
         var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();
         chart.series[0].addPoint([current_time, Math.random()*10], false);  
         chart.redraw();    
}

setInterval(addPoints,3000);
```

Please see jsFiddle demo of the issue :

http://jsfiddle.net/ehonk/FLzRH/1/

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The "popping" is the data being added and the line connecting the last point to the new point and the yAxis re-scaling. To minimize this I would set the [`yAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.max) to a value that is the maximum possible. Secondly I would look at the animation and see which kind you want to use when it [adds](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.addPoint) a new point.

To handle the "sqeezing" you can set your "viewable" range and your adding of points such that when you add a new point the last point on the left falls out of the viewable area.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) to set range on the xAxis.